# cmd save " character to a file without new line

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Is that possible save a special character " to a string without new line?
I tried below codes ,but none of them working:

```
echo|set /p=""" >>C:\text.txt
echo|set /p=" >>C:\text.txt
echo|set /p=^" >>C:\text.txt
set /p=""" <nul >> C:\text.txt
set /p=" <nul >> C:\text.txt
set /p=^" <nul >> C:\text.txt
```

Comment: Your fourth one will work, but you have to hit enter to continue.

Comment: You could `powershell "write-host -nonewline '\"'" >>c:\test.txt`.  You could also have the contents of quote.txt as `"` with no trailing new line and `copy c:\test.txt + quote.txt c:\test2.txt` maybe?

Comment: Thanks for reply,SomethingDark,I tried like I said,even hit enter,there is no text.txt file created in my c driver,I am using Win7 64 bit.

Comment: Hi, rojo,I could do it with other way,but now I just need cmd in command line to finish it directly,can it possilbe?

Comment: You cannot write to the root of the C: drive unless you are running an elevated cmd prompt.

Comment: Change to d or other driver,also as the same result,you can try yourself.

Comment: I commented that your fourth one works because it worked for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost had it

```
<nul >"file.txt" set/p="""
```

but, as Squashman points, if you try to write to the root of your drive, you will need an elevated prompt

Answer (score 4):

Here is a slightly different method which does not require the redirection to be put in front of the `set /P` command:

```cmd
set /P =""^" < nul >> "C:\text.txt"
```

Since the last of the three quotation marks is escaped like `^"`, the remaining command line portion does not appear quoted and therefore, the redirection operators `<` and `>>` are recognised.

Answer (score 2):

Not a one-liner in the command-prompt but as a batch-file the following works for me:

```
>>output.txt (
echo|set/p="""
)
```

Or if you want to hit return to write it use the following, very similar one:

```
>>output.txt (
set /p=""" < nul
)
```

One could as well establish it to be a kind of a function to use dynamically:

```
>>"%~dp1" (
echo|set/p="""
)
```

To use this one, you pass the filename as first command-line argument as the following:

> addQuoteTo.bat "C:\my Path\toFile\file.txt"

Was an interesting thing to play around with :)